# How do I send commands from a Windows GUI to a Linux machine over the network?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, ssh, putty

**Some Background -**

I have written a C program on the TS-7800 (running Debian Linux) which I access through Putty. The program is essentially in charge of controlling DAC/ADC's in order to modify the state of a memory element.

My next task is to develop a GUI for that program. The GUI is built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in C++. I've made most of the GUI and simply need a way to send the data which I collect to the Linux machine.

My first attempt was to invoke a connection with Putty through command line from the GUI, and then try to send various commands through that Putty connection. The drawback here is that once I invoke a connection with Putty using the command putty username@192.168.1.50, it is done in the foreground, rather then hidden in the background, and I don't know how to continue entering text/commands from the GUI into Putty once it has been launched.

**My Question -**

How should I go about connecting my GUI on Windows to the program on the Linux machine? Is my attempt with Putty a step in the right direction, or should I be taking a different approach - possibly Cygwin?

Thank you in advance for any help - this is my first post on stackoverflow so please forgive me if I've mistakenly overlooked some detail or if I did not abide by proper etiquette.

Comment: That depends on how you want the linux machine to receive it.  Did you want the GUI to write it to a file and send the file? Did you want to have a linux daemon run a webservice that the GUI could call? You could do RPC, HTTP, FTP, NFS, shares, raw sockets, or you could have the GUI drive a terminal connection and have it emulate typing stuff to the other program if it is designed to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow some protocol to interact with the server. Then your GUI needs to follow that protocol to send commands to the server.

Probably, you are talking about SSH connection with server. There are a lots of SSH Client library available in windows. You can use one in your GUI to interact.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you recommend an SSH client?

Comment: try openssh library. boost also has ssh support.

Comment: Thanks! This was a step in the right direction. I ended up using socket communication between the two to send simple commands to the board and receive data.

Comment: @Bhai could you provide a link? I'm very interested in using SSH with BOOST.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It's a very solid asynchronous IO library included in boost. (You will need to build it however).